# What is the point of CodeNamespaceImport when the compiler doesn't need nor use it?

Tags: c#, code-generation, codedom

Consider the follow code sample (copy-pastable in LINQPad):

```
void Main()
{
    var ttNamespace = new CodeNamespace("SampleNamespace");
    ttNamespace.Imports.AddRange(new[]{"System", "System.Text", "System.Threading"}.Select(x => new CodeNamespaceImport(x)).ToArray());

    var newType = new CodeTypeDeclaration("SampleClass")
    {
        TypeAttributes = TypeAttributes.Public
    };

    var newField = new CodeMemberField(typeof(List<int>), "_field")
    {
        Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public
    };

    newField.InitExpression = new CodeObjectCreateExpression(new CodeTypeReference(typeof(List<int>)), new CodeExpression[] { });

    newType.Members.Add(newField);
    ttNamespace.Types.Add(newType);

    var parameters = new CompilerParameters()
    {
        GenerateExecutable = false,
        OutputAssembly = @"C:\test.dll"
    };

    var ccUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
    ccUnit.Namespaces.Add(ttNamespace);

    var result = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#").CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, ccUnit);

    Console.WriteLine (result.Errors);
}
```

As you can see, I explicitly add namespaces `System`, `System.Text` and `System.Threading`. I also utilize the type `List<int>` but don't provide a namespace import for `System.Collections.Generic`.

Logically this should result in an error somewhere down the line. Maybe not at compile time, but definitely at runtime. This is not the case though, the code compiles to this:

> [image]

We can see that all `using` statements have already been organized for us: redundant ones are left out and required ones are added. Obviously this is very useful but this begs the question:

What is the point of explicit [`CodeNamespaceImport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codenamespaceimport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) statements when the compiler doesn't use it anyway?

I should note that completely omitting the adding of my namespaces doesn't change the output at all: it keeps working as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point, `typeof(List<int>)` is unambiguous in *your* program and can generate the full type name of List.  It isn't very clear where you got the source listing from, I suspect you used a disassembler that automatically figured out which *using* directives where most useful.

You can modify the program like this to see what the compiler *really* sees:

```
        var prov = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
        var gen = prov.CreateGenerator();
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\temp\\test.cs")) {
            gen.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(ccUnit, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
        }

        var result = prov.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, ccUnit);
```

Which produces:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.34011
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace SampleNamespace {
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;


    public class SampleClass {

        public System.Collections.Generic.List<int> _field = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
    }
}
```

As you can tell, the compiler actually sees the full type name and the *using* directives are not necessary.

Comment: Ah, this clears up a lot. Who exactly is most likely to be the cause of this difference: ILSpy or the CodeDomProvider when assembling it into an assembly? If I understand you correctly, does this mean I don't have to add `CodeNamespaceImports` when I know the exact type in the calling program?

Comment: As I guessed, you used a disassembler.  It doesn't tell you what the source code looked like, only what the DLL looks like.  And no, not necessary unless you generate code for a human.

Comment: Cheers, that distinction between actual source and interpreted source is a nasty pitfall.

Answer (score 1):

At the IL level, there are no namespace imports, all types are always referenced using their full name.

So, when a decompiler generates C# from IL, it doesn't know what namespace imports did the original code contain. This means that a reasonable decompiler will probably generate code that imports all namespaces that are used in a class (unless that would cause conflicts).